# How to highlight a text with double simple quotes '' in a HTML section

Tags: dokuwiki

I'd like to highlight one or two words in a `<HTML></HTML>` section in a dokuwiki (2014-05-05 "Ponder Stibbons") page like I'd do outside of the section with `''one or two words''` or with apostrophe in SE markdown. How can I achieve that? Example (`embedded HTML` option has to be enabled in configuration):

```
====== Title ======
<HTML>
  <ul>
    <li>Magic should happen ''here'', except not with '' because it isn't recognized</li>
  </ul>
</HTML>
```

The following doesn't suit my needs

- `<tt>one two</tt>` simply doesn't look the same

Besides this I don't have any ideas...

Comment: Have you tried something? You tagged your question with dokuwiki, why? Are you trying to format a dokuwiki page? Please add precisions to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the string in &quot tag like &quotkey&quot i.e. &quot tag appended with semicolon

May be misunderstood your question , now more clear 
Try something like this if it helps by enclosing in code tags as shown in :
[https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:lists](https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq%3alists)

`Magic should happen 'here', expect not with because it isn't recognized`

Also,check out the following link :

[https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax](https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki%3asyntax)

Comment: That just replaces `&quot` with `"`. Can you post the code that you used to try this, please?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can add html extensively to docuwiki just checkout the links I shared

Comment: 100.0 % what I was looking for :)